# Transient response of active filter attenuation

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, active-filter

I simulated a 5th order active high pass filter on LTSpice. However I find that the output voltage does not have same attenuation as the magnitude response plot.

At 10Hz it is expected to have a 100dB attenuation which should yield 10uV. However, the transient simulation shows that the output voltage is 4.91mV which is only -46dB with respect to a 1V 10Hz input.

Is this some form of op-amp saturation or an error in the circuit? I'm still new to simulating circuits.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: TRANSIENT SIMULATION INPUT
[image]

EDIT 3:

[image]

Comment: What response are you simulating? Step response? Sinusoidal input? Impulse response?

Comment: its a 1V SINE at 10Hz I have re-edited to include my input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a high dynamic range so you need to tell the solver to tighten the timestep. For example here's a 5th order Butterworth highpass with a 100 dB attenuation at 1 kHz:

[image: .AC]

And here is how the simulation looks like with no timestep imposed for an input sine of 1 V, 1 kHz (`.tran 100m`):

[image: no timestep]

versus a 10 μs imposed timestep (`.tran 0 100m 0 10u`):

[image: with timestep]

Optionally, you may want to disable waveform compression by adding `.opt plotwinsize=0` to the schematic, but be careful because the `.RAW` file may grow unruly.

Comment: I have changed the timestep as per your suggestion however I think timestep may not be the issue? I have added my required input in edit (1V SINE at 10Hz)

Comment: @FreddyBoat If you look at the last two pictures above you'll see that the timescale shows `90m ... 100m`. That means I have simulated for at least `100m`, out of which I zoomed in in the last portion. In your picture, not only you kept right at the beginning, but you've also not zoomed in to the uV region. Not lastly, don't forget that no real-time process is instantaneous in nature, and filters have a transient response. This is why I chose the last section of the timescale, as opposed to the beginning -- to let the transients decay.

Comment: In my second picture, my cursor is at 0.5s/500ms which isn't it considered steady state already? I looked into output at 1s as well, it seems to be going flat at 4.92..mV which zooming in and averaging waves at 4.9 does not make it to uV . Sorry, I may be misinterpreting you.

Comment: @FreddyBoat In your 1st picture, yes, but then you didn't use a timestep there, did you? In your 2nd picture you did, but in both pictures you're relying on the cursors to read values in the uV range when zoomed out into V range. It's like trying to run your fingers over a glass surface and detect, bare handed, whether there are irregularities in the tens of micro meter range. Zoom in if you need details. Look at my pictures: the Y axis is in the uV range, yours is in the mV range -- that's 1000x times larger. You could barely see 0.1 mV a variation, let alone uV.

Comment: Maybe you don't know how to zoom in? I don't know what you know, but in case you don't know, if you'll open up the manual (`F1`) and go to *Waveform Viewer > Zooming* you'll see that it's as easy as click & drag with the LMouse to create a box (you'll see the cursor turning into a magnifier).

Comment: I took another screenshot, can you have a look again

Comment: @FreddyBoat Please don't just zoom in mindlessly. You're zooming in a range of 1 us. How does that compare to your signal's period? Use this simulation command" `.tran 0 10 9 0.1m` and tell me what you see. If you want to see the complete response then replace `9` with `0`.

Comment: I see you've edited your answer in the meantime. Now you can see that you have a signal that's about 20 uV p-p, on top of about 4 mV DC, which is the result of bias. Every opamp has it. If you want to cancel that you have to either use corrective circuits, or a simple capacitor at the output, to cancel the DC. Don't forget that if you want to probe the output you'll need a terminating resistance -- a floating capacitor will not work the way you think.

Comment: ah so the output voltage is not the average between p-p (4.918mV) instead its about 10uV with added bias from the op-amp which shifts it up to 4mV correct? this may be the question i was initially wanted to ask, however i guess the fact that i did not provide a zoomed in plot made my question unclear

Comment: May i know what's the proper term of this effect? is it just op-amp DC bias?

Comment: @FreddyBoat If you look in various datasheets for opamps you'll see it named offset voltage (there's also current). If your opamp stage has a gain of 10 and the input offset is 1 mV, you'll see 10 mV at the output.

Comment: Thanks for help, I was confused about the need to zoom in to find the average since I was expecting a result like yours centered at 0V therefore I was hesitant to do so. The answer I was looking for I suppose is this offset effect.

Comment: @FreddyBoat I used an ideal filter, so no offset there (the 1st picture whows a perfect -100 dB @ 1 kHz).

Comment: The datasheet for this component shows typical input offset of 150uV when connected to +5V and 0V. I assume this is different because I have a cascade and also the fact I have +/-5V supply. Albeit all having unity gain.

Comment: @FreddyBoat The first thing that you should do before testing your filter is to verify the operating point. In LTspice that's commenting out all the other simulation cards and adding `.OP`. It will display a list of voltages and currents. If you dismiss that and then simply LClick on nodes, you'll place a label holding the value of the voltage at that node. If you RClick on the label you can change it to whatever other quantity is available. Some math is can also be done. See the help for more.